# Solve linear system with variation of 2 parameters

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, discrete-mathematics, systems-of-equations

**Solve linear system with variation of 2 parameters:**
$$\begin{cases} hx+2ky+kz = 0 \\ hx-6y+z = 1 \end{cases}$$
I suppose to view all possible cases of combinations of $k$ and $h$ so ($h=0$,$k=0$),($h=0$,$k\ne0$), ($h\ne0$,$k=0$) and ($h\ne0$,$k\ne0$), since $\begin{vmatrix} -2k & k \\ -6  & 1 \end{vmatrix} = 4k,\  4k =0 \iff k = 0$

My steps:
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} h & -2k & k \\ h & -6 &1  \end{pmatrix}$$
$$\overline A = \begin{pmatrix} h & -2k & k & 0\\ h & -6 &1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

1. $h \ne 0$, $k=0$

$$\begin{cases} hx = 0 \\ hx -6 y +z = 1 \end{cases} \ \begin{cases} hx = 0 \\ -6 y = 1 -z \end{cases}$$
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} h & 0 \\ 0 & -6\end{pmatrix}$$ $$\overline A = \begin{pmatrix} h & 0 & 0\\ 0 & -6 & 1-z\end{pmatrix}$$
That gives this solution:
$S = \{(0, \frac{h-zh}{-6h}, z)| h, z \in \mathbb{R}\}$

2. $h \ne 0, k \ne 0$

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} h & -2k & k \\ h & -6 &1  \end{pmatrix}$$
$$\overline A = \begin{pmatrix} h & -2k & k & 0\\ h & -6 &1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$\begin{cases} -2ky +kz = 0 \\ -6y+z = 1 \end{cases}$$
That gives this solution:
$S = \{(-\frac{1}{4}, -\frac{1}{2}, z)| z \in \mathbb{R}\}$

3. $h = 0, k = 0$
   $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -6 &1  \end{pmatrix}$$
   $$\overline A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & -6 &1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
   That gives null solution.
4. $h = 0, k \ne 0$
   $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -2k & k \\ 0 & -6 & 1  \end{pmatrix}$$
   $$\overline A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -2k & k & 0\\ 0 & -6 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

That gives this solution:
$S = \{(-\frac{1}{4}, -\frac{1}{2}, z)| z \in \mathbb{R}\}$

Are my solutions (or at least my steps) right?

I noticed that solve this type of exercise takes so so much time, maybe because I'm doing something wrong, but in any case, there's a faster way?

Comment: `h=0,k=0 ... gives null solution` It is not clear how you derive those result sets. If $h=k=0$ for example, the equations reduce to $0=0$ and $-6y+z=0$ so the solution set is $\{(x,y,6y) \mid x,y \in \mathbb R\}$.

Comment: @dxiv why the second equation is not $-6y+z = 1 \iff z = 1+6y$, I shouldn't consider the known terms column?

Comment: Right, I missed the $1$ there. But the solution set is still the double infinity of triplets $(x,y,6y+1)$.

Comment: @dxiv I double-checked, you're right, thanks!